# WPF Multiple DataContexts

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I'm writing a very simple application, but am having problems with how to deal with the Linq to SQL DataContexts, because every time I try to do something which I think should be simple, I get an error saying something like, `you can't update entity because it was generated from different data context`.

#### Data Model

I have a `Configuration` object which can contain multiple `ConfigurationFilter` and is associated to a `User`.

A `ConfigurationFilter` contains a reference to a `Filter` and a `FilterValue`

#### The simple example

On my ViewModel constructor, I do something like:

```
public ViewModel() {
  using (LinqDataContext dc = new LinqDataContext()) {
    this.User = dc.User;
    this.Configuration = new Configuration{ User = this.User };
  }
}
```

And then, later on, I can edit the configuration name and description and I have a save command that does:

```
public void save() {
   this.Configuration.Name = this.ConfigurationName;
   this.Configuration.Description = this.ConfigurationDescription;
   using (LinqDataContext dc = new LinqDataContext()) {
      dc.Configurations.AddObject(this.Configuration);
      dc.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

This will return some error (I suppose because I'm using the `User` which was created in a different context. The error (and syntax) is different whether I'm using EF or linq-to-sql. In this case it's `The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null.`

#### My current solution

Right now, my solution is whenever I have a new object, I assign only IDs to the properties instead of objects:

```
this.UserID = dc.User.UserID;
```

And for existing objects, I load the old object from a new data context, and then have methods that compare the old and modified objects and recreate all the changes. **But this seems very stupid and there must be a better way, which I don't know!!!**

Is it better to just pass the original LinqDataContext around (or create a static/singleton LinqDataContext)?

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a new `DataContext` every time you're updating values. Only one is necessary, and if your View is bound to your `DataContext`, it can be very inefficient to recreate it because all the bindings have to be regenerated.

Comment: Does that mean that I should be passing the `DataContext` around? My View is bound to a ViewModel and never directly to the results of the `DataContext` queries.

Comment: Ideally, your ViewModel IS the DataContext for your View. I'm not sure how you have things structured, but it looks like you have a separate ViewModel class that is retrieving values from a DataContext that is itself bound to a view? If true, you've got an extra, potentially unnecessary layer in your architecture.

Comment: Why don't you simply create a property that you will be setting whether via the constructor or in the xaml (depending on how you init your viewmodels). Nothing complicated here...

Comment: Also, If I may, you should move you business logics (`save()` or whatever) from view model to model. **model** is not the model we use to know with MVC, It's both Data and business logic

Comment: @WasGoodDone my ViewModel is the DataContext for my View. The DataContext I mention is the one I use from Linq to SQL, which is the way I use to retrieve the data from the database. Thanks